# Why do we need adsense to sign up for admob

Tags: android, admob, adsense

I want to use admob in an android app I built. I dont have any websites for the app and therefore I can't signup with adsense because they ask for a website url. What options do I have?

Comment: Couldn't you create a Google Sites page and point it at that?

Comment: uhm maybe, how can one do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Google site, by going here (having first logged into your Google account):

https://sites.google.com/

There's some help here:

https://support.google.com/sites/?hl=en-GB#topic=1689606

But to be honest it's pretty easy to pick a pre-defined template and get something knocked up pretty quickly, especially if you just want some sort of holding page.

Comment: yup i went and signedup for a site and luckily found a nice location name! thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

When you create admob, by default it connects it so adsense. Can't you put blank website? If it does not let you continue then put url for any any website you have. It won't be used anyways

Comment: because google disapproved my adsense account because i had an underconstruction site. I could use another website name but didnt know you could put blank websites.