# How do I sign up for AdMob without a website?

Tags: android

I am trying to publish an app that will use mobile ads to generate revenue.

When I try to sign up for AdMob, it tells me that I must have an AdSense account.

When I go to sign up for AdSense, it tells me that I must have a website.

I don't have a website.  I have an app.

But the Adsense insists that I have one.  Some helpful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211573/why-do-we-need-adsense-to-sign-up-for-admob) indicated that if I create a blog with google, then I can use that as my "website".  I did that, both on [sites.google.com](http://sites.google.com) and [blogger](http://www.blogger.com/).  If I try to use either of those to sign up with AdSense, it tells me that I must sign up for Adsense directly though either "sites.google.com" or "www.blogger.com" respectively.

"sites.google.com" apparently no longer supports new AdSense account, so I abandoned that avenue.  Blogger does support it, but when I go to "Enable Earnings" it tells me that my blog is not eligible.  It doesn't give me a reason, but it's likely because my "blog" has no content.

I don't want to write a blog, I want to publish an APP!!

So my question is:
1)  Is it possible to get google mobile ads (yes, I'd like to use google so it integrates nicely with firebase, etc). without a website?
2)  if (1) is a no, then how can I quickly and easily satisfy google that my blog/website/whatever is legit enough to warrant an Adsense account?

This has easily been the most frustrating part of launching this app, and that includes hunting down bugs in my code.

sorry if this is off topic, if there is a better forum please point me to it.

Comment: I don't think we need a website to add AdMob, are you following instructions in given in: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6383165

Comment: I can't follow those instructions, as the first step is to sign into my admob account.   That is what I cannot do.

Comment: You don't need a website to use admob

Comment: When I go to sign in to Admob, it says "AdMob requires a valid AdSense account and AdWords account. However, there seems to be a problem with one or both of your accounts."  then, below that, in red, it says "AdSense
You do not have access to the account that is connected to your AdMob account."  When I try to go to AdSense to investigate, it says I have no account and asks me to sign up.  That's when it asks me for a website.

Comment: My website is my blog on blogger. It works for me.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Instead of a blog I created a web page on one of my domains but it is not working. About your blog on blogger, is it empty? or you need to put some information about your app?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem and found the solution here : https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/Xea6bNSJP1A

Basically, your Google account is now "marked" and you can't create an adsense account with that Google account unless you can provide a website/active blog address.

I created a second Google account and was able to sign up for Admob smoothly.